# Do Apache slaves need SSL setting up, if master is SSL?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate

We currently have a working setup on Apache 2.2 just using http.

We have 1 front end server for basic page server, and for certain urls we forward to a slave/proxy server. We do this via a simple server list, eg

```
master is somedomain.com (not mydomain.net)

RewriteMap servers rnd:/www/myserverlist.txt
RewriteRule ^/somessearch$    http://${servers:list}/somesearch  [P,L]
```

myserverlist.txt would contain

```
list    search1.mydomain.net,search2.mydomain.net
```

This all currently works with http, and does some simply loadsharing, passing work off to other servers. These servers are in the same subnet and location, but have different domains (but the slave domain isn't exposed to client).

We are going to upgrade to SSL, and have an cert ready on the front end master (we have SSL working for a separate front end only domain).

Will the requests and 'slaves' need some SSL setup as well (and any idea what that would be, I'm strugging to find something relevant to our setup) ? Or can this still be passed to an http slave (on the basis, it's not a remote device and the client wouldn't see this side, there is no sensitive info)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use HTTPS when connecting from your front-end TLS termination proxy to your back-end web-servers.

You should however consider, that in case you do not completely control the network in between the front- and back-end apache, or a host on the network has been compromised, an attacker could possibly sniff the unencrypted traffic between the the front-end TLS proxy and your back-end webservers.